# NullPointerException is thrown when Custom ViewHandler is used

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish-3

I'm trying to use a custom ViewHandler in my application built with JSF2, PrimeFaces 3.2.x and deployed on Glassfish AS v3.1.1. Once I added my custom ViewHandler in faces-config.xml, the first page is rendered fine, but any action leads to NPE. I modified my ViewHandler so it does nothing but proxying to a parent ViewHandler, but the problem persists.

The code for CustomViewHandler

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.faces.FacesException;
import javax.faces.application.ViewHandler;
import javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class CustomViewHandler extends ViewHandler {
    private ViewHandler parent;

    public CustomViewHandler(ViewHandler parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public UIViewRoot restoreView(FacesContext facesContext, String viewId) {
        return parent.restoreView(facesContext, viewId);
    }

    @Override
    public Locale calculateLocale(FacesContext facesContext) {
        return parent.calculateLocale(facesContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String calculateRenderKitId(FacesContext facesContext) {
        return parent.calculateRenderKitId(facesContext);
    }

    @Override
    public UIViewRoot createView(FacesContext facesContext, String viewId) {
        return parent.createView(facesContext, viewId);
    }

    @Override
    public String getActionURL(FacesContext facesContext, String actionId) {
        return parent.getActionURL(facesContext, actionId);
    }

    @Override
    public String getResourceURL(FacesContext facesContext, String resId) {
        return parent.getResourceURL(facesContext, resId);
    }

    @Override
    public void renderView(FacesContext facesContext, UIViewRoot viewId) throws IOException, FacesException {
        parent.renderView(facesContext, viewId);

    }

    @Override
    public void writeState(FacesContext facesContext) throws IOException {
        parent.writeState(facesContext);
    }

    public ViewHandler getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
}
```

My faces-config.xml

```
<application>
    <view-handler>com.util.CustomViewHandler</view-handler>
    <message-bundle>messages</message-bundle>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <resource-bundle>
       <base-name>messages</base-name>
       <var>msg</var>
     </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.getRenderer(UIComponentBase.java:1402)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:785)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1181)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:933)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at com.seer.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:21)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:232)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Thanks

Comment: Having exactly same issue on glassfish 3.1.2, also using primefaces 3.4.

Comment: I still do not have a solution for this issue. I've not tried this approach since the time I posted the message. I do not need it right now, I was just playing around with the functionality that I might need in future. I did not have enough time to come back and play more with this. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, but by extending the `ViewHandlerWrapper` instead of the the `ViewHandler` it solves the error.

Here is an example of my `CustomViewHandler` (not a complete example, but was built within our app as a proof of concept) :

```
import javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException;
import javax.faces.application.ViewHandler;
import javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper;
import javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class CustomViewHandler extends ViewHandlerWrapper {

    private ViewHandler wrapped;
    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CustomViewHandler.class);
    
    public CustomViewHandler(ViewHandler wrapped) {
        LOGGER.info("CustomViewHandler.CustomViewHandler():wrapped View Handler:"+wrapped.getClass());
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public UIViewRoot restoreView(FacesContext context, String viewId) {
        UIViewRoot root;
        try {
            LOGGER.info("restoring view : " + viewId);
            root = wrapped.restoreView(context, viewId);
        } catch (ViewExpiredException e) {
            LOGGER.error("View Expired : " + e.getMessage() + " -> recreating");
            root = wrapped.createView(context, viewId);
        }
        return root;
    }
    
    @Override
    public ViewHandler getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }
}
```

If you want a more complete and functional custom view handler, look at the `OmniFaces` [RestorableViewHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/enableRestorableView).  Source code is available on that page.

### From Java Doc

> #### javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper
>
> Provides a simple implementation of ViewHandler that can be subclassed by developers wishing to provide specialized behavior to an existing ViewHandler instance. The default implementation of all methods is to call through to the wrapped ViewHandler.
>
> Usage: extend this class and override getWrapped to return the instance we are wrapping.